# Showing properties of unitary operator

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, orthonormal

Let $H_1, H_2$ be Hilbert spaces and $T:H_1\to H_2$.
We say that $T$ is unitary if it preserves the inner product and unto.

1. Show that the following claims are equivalent:

A. $T$ is unitary.

B. T copies every orthonormal basis of H to an orthonormal basis of H.

C. T is injective and there exist an orthonormal basis of $H_1$ such that $T$ copies to an orthonormal basis of $H_2$.

D. T is invertible and $T^{-1}=T^*$

2. Show that $T$ is unitary iff $T^*$ is.
3. if $H_1=H_2$.
   Show that $T$ is unitary iff $T$ preserves the inner product and is normal.

For 1:

A=>B:
Let T be an unitary operator, i.e it preserves the inner product.
Let $(u_a)\in H$ be a hilbert basis of H (for every hilbert space there's an orthonormal basis), then
$<Tu_a,Tu_b>=<u_a,u_b>=0$ for all $a\neq b$ and
$<Tu_a,Tu_a>=<u_a,u_a>=1$.
Thus, T copies the orthonormal basis $(u_a)$ to an orthonormal basis $(Tu_a)$.

D=>A:
Let T be invertible and $T^*=T^{-1}$.
Then, $<Tx,Ty>=<x,T^*Ty>=<x,y>$ so T is unitary by definition.

For 2:
Using that A <=>D
T is unitary iff it is invertible and $T^{-1}=T^*$.

If T is unitary then $<T^*x,T^*y>=<x,TT^*y>=<x,Iy>=<x,y>$, we get that $T^*$ is unitry.
In the second way, if $T^*$ is unitary, then
$<Tx,Ty>=<x,T^*Ty>=<x,y>$, so T is unitary.

For 3:
If T is unitary then T preservess the inner product (by def), and using A <=> D,

$T^*T=T^{-1}T=I$
$TT^*=TT^{-1}=I$
Therefore T is normal.

For the inverse, let T be norml and preseres the inner product,
$<Tx,Ty>=<x,T^*Ty>=<x,TT^*y>=<x,y>$, so $T^*T=TT^*=I$, so T is invertible and $T^*=T^{-1}$, thus T is unitary (by A <=>D).

Is what i did fine?

I did not get the idea in the rest => in 1, so will appreciate your help.

Comment: in order to show that A,B,C,D are all equivalent, you need to show (for example) that B follows from A and that C follows from B and that D follows from C and that A follows from D. These are kinda separate problems. Can you do any of them? which one(s) are you stuck on? You will probably attract more help if you can be more specific.

Comment: Some of your existing proof is incomplete. For 1a->1b you show that T maps an orthonormal basis to an orthnormal set, but not why this set is a basis (i.e. a complete orthonormal set.)  In 1d -> 1a you should mention that T is unto because it's invertible.  Similarly for 2 you should mention the invertability implies the necessary unto-ness in either direction.

Comment: Hi @O. Peters thanks! For the response. Can I ask in 1a=>1b how we can deduce that the set is a basis?

Comment: Because you're given that $T$ is unto, so for any $y\in H_2$ there's an $x\in H_1$ such that $T(x)=y$.  So if $y=T(x)$ is orthogonal to all the $T(u_a)$, show that $x$ is orthogonal to all the $u_a$, and since the $u_a$ are a basis implies $x=0$ so $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1b->1c
Well, first I hope you believe $H_1$ has some orthonormal basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ (it's a matter of axiom of choice).  Then since in 1b you assume $T$ maps any orthnormal basis of $H_1$ to an orthonormal basis of $H_2$, then specifically $\{T(e_i)\}_{i\in I}$ must be an orthonormal basis of $H_2$.  Now, for $i, j$ we have $\langle e_i, T^{*} T(e_j) \rangle = \langle T(e_i), T (e_j) \rangle = \delta^i_j$ which proves that $T^{*} T(e_i) = e_i$ for all $i \in I$. To show injectivity, assume $T(x) = 0$.  Then $\langle x, e_i \rangle =\langle x, T^{*}T(e_i) \rangle = \langle T(x), T(e_i) \rangle = 0$ for all $i \in I$.  Since $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis this implies $x = 0$.

Note: I did not justify why $T^{*}$ exists.  The question doesn't state what we know about $T$.  I assume it's linear and defined on all of $H_1$.  Even if we don't assume that $T$ is bounded, from the fact that it maps any orthonormal basis to an orthonormal basis and since any unit vector is part of an orthonormal basis, $T$ maps the unit ball into the unit ball so is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

So just for completion 1c->1d
First assume that $T$ is bounded.  Then $T^*$ is defined and bounded.  Letting $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an orthonormal basis mapped by $T$ to some orthnormal basis, and proceeding as above shows that $T^* T(e_i) = e_i$ for all $i\in I$ and this proves that $T^* T = \text{id}_{H_1}$.  Note that the assumed injectivity is not even used, but follows from this conclusion.  Swapping the roles of the orthonormal bases $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{T(e_i)\}_{i\in I}$ we conclude that $T T^*=\text{id}_{H_2}$ which completes the proof of 1d.

Now what if we don't assume that $T$ is bounded?  Then it's flat out wrong that $T$ has to be unitary.  Let $H$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\mathcal{A}\subset H$.  Let $\mathcal{B}\subset H$ be a family of vectors completing $\mathcal{A}$ to a **Hamel** basis of $H$.  In other words $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}=\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$ is a linear basis of $H$.  Note that $\mathcal{A}$ is countable but $|\mathcal{B}|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$  Let $y$ be any element of $\mathcal{B}$ and define an operator $T:H\rightarrow H$ by setting $$T(y)=2y$$ and $$T(x)=x$$ for all $x\in\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\neq y$.  Then

1. $T$ can be extended uniquely to a linear operator with domain $H$.
2. $T$ is injective and in fact bijective because it maps a linear basis to a linear basis.
3. $T$ maps the orthonormal basis $\mathcal{A}$ to an orthnormal basis (itself.)
4. $T$ is not unitary because it does not preserve the norm of $y$.

It follows as a conclustion that $T$ cannot be bounded because if $T$ were bounded then the proof that it is unitary would apply.  This means for instance that $T$ maps unit vectors to vectors of arbitrarily large norm even though this is not evident from its definition.
So unlike the other criteria, in 1c the boundedness of $T$ needs to be assumed, and the assumption of injectivity on the other hand is unnecessary.